# Blowback on jQuery setTimeout

Tags: jquery, scroll, settimeout

I trie to use a timeout function in an if query, more specifically in a scroll function.

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 400) {
     setTimeout(function() {
        $(".stickfullsize").addClass("hide");
}, 1000);
    } else {
        $(".stickfullsize").removeClass("hide");
    }
});
</script>
```

At the first moment, everything seems to work, but he put the class "hide" back after removing.
I've tried several options seen here on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me. I think the problem is, that the function goes on and on in settimeout when scrolling, but I don't no how to handle.

**All I want to reach:**
Add a class to a div with a set delay after scrolled >=400 from top and remove it on scrolling <400 to top of the page.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your code looks like it should do that (although it will schedule a **lot** of timer callbacks that all add the class even when it's already added). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably running into trouble because as you cross the boundary, you can be removing the class when the timer is outstanding (and will add it later) and other such cross-talk.

To avoid it, only add the timer when you haven't already added it, and remove it when the scrolltop goes to `< 400`.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var stickfullsize = $(".stickfullsize");

    if (scroll >= 400) {
        // Only schedule it if it's not scheduled yet and doesn't have the class
        if (!scrollTimer && !stickfullsize.hasClass("hide")) {
            scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                stickfullsize.addClass("hide");
                scrollTimer = 0;
            }, 1000);
        }
    } else {
        // Clear it if it's set
        if (scrollTimer) {
            clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
            scrollTimer = 0;
        }
        stickfullsize.removeClass("hide");
    }
});
```

Live Example (using `>= 100` instead of `>= 400`):

```js
for (var n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
    $("<div>").text("Div " + n).appendTo(document.body);
}
$("div:eq(21)").addClass("stickfullsize");
var timerSpan = $(".timer");
var scrollSpan = $(".scrolltop");

var scrollTimer = 0;

function updateStatus() {
    timerSpan.text(
        (scrollTimer ? "pending" : "not pending") +
        ($(".stickfullsize").hasClass("hide") ? " has class" : "")
    );
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var stickfullsize = $(".stickfullsize");
    scrollSpan.text(String(scroll));
    if (scroll >= 100) {
        // Only schedule it if it's not scheduled yet
        if (!scrollTimer && !stickfullsize.hasClass("hide")) {
            scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                stickfullsize.addClass("hide");
                scrollTimer = 0;
                updateStatus();
            }, 1000);
        }
    } else {
        // Clear it if it's set
        if (scrollTimer) {
            clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
            scrollTimer = 0;
        }
        stickfullsize.removeClass("hide");
    }
    updateStatus();
});
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.hide {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
.status {
    position: fixed;
    height: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="status">
  <span class="scrolltop">0</span>
  <span class="timer"></span>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You safed my day! Tank you so much. I was sure that the error must be in the timer function. I did not come for a further examination in the exam. saved in my brain :)